# Best strategy to deal with large complex mongodb queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a some queries that update multiple mongodb collections. Running a query for one item is fine but as soon as I have to do this on a few hundred items the query times out and I get memory problems in my node.js app.
Is there a way to process queries so they don't run immediately?
I don't need the query result right away.

Thanks

Comment: What is your exact problem? Are your update queries running slow or select queries?

Comment: If your query is complex and involve multiple tables then you should not use mongodb. use a relation database like ms sql, my sql etc

Comment: @ManishKumawat collections*

Comment: @bar.m lol :) correct

Comment: The only problem I have is that the queries (update and select) are timing out and the node app instance is running out of memory. It would be interesting to know if there is a way to control that.